# sway to or sway into

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, infinitive-vs-gerund

Can I use the 2nd sentence instead of the first one:

1. I was swayed by her rhetoric into donating all my savings to the charity.
2. I was swayed by her rhetoric to donate all my saving to the charity

Comment: It's an interesting question, but I'm actually not sure it has anything to do with the word "sway".  I would use *into* pretty much regardless of what verb was there: I was *talked* into donating, I was *pressured* into donating, I was *tricked* into donating, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Both seem ok, but I prefer "to donate" over "into donating".  If I recall both the infinitive form (to X) and the gerund form (X-ing) act as the same part of speech here, so it's more a question of personal taste and style than grammar.

It also varies depending on which verb or idiomatic expression is used.  For example:

> She convinced me to bake her a cake.
>
> She talked me into baking her a cake.

"Swayed by her rhetoric" is an unusual enough phrase that there doesn't seem to be a preference one way or the other.  But as written, it's an awkward sentence, which I would rewrite as a compound sentence:

> I was swayed by her rhetoric, so much so that I donated all my savings to the charity.

Answer (score 2):

Her speech failed to sway her colleagues into supporting the plan (Cambridge).

I think I can sway her to join our side (The Free Dictionary).

In light of these sentences, I think you can use either the construction   sway + somebody + into +  an -ing form" or the construction   "sway + somebody + a to-nfinitive".

Furthermore, it's more appropriate and common to say savings instead of saving and charity instead of the charity in the sentence presented.